# Change property name from an array of object javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of obect  lets call it "myArray":

```
0: { name: "name1", key: "12weqw3123123"}
1: { name: "name2", key: "1231231rasd"}
2: { name: "name3", key: "sa43214dasd"}
```

What I would like to achieve is to switch the properties naming form name to key and the opposite so the final result is something like that:

```
0: { key: "name1", name: "12weqw3123123"}
1: { key: "name2", name: "1231231rasd"}
2: { key: "name3", name: "sa43214dasd"}
```

I tried with

```
  const { name } = myArray;
  const newResp = { key: name };
```

but its undefined and I tried also with

```
const newArray = [...myArray].map((r: { name: any; key: any }) => {
    r.name = r.key;
    delete r.key;
  });
```

any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle it with a `forEach`:

```
myArray.forEach(item => {
    let tmp = item.key;
    item.key = item.name;
    item.name = tmp;
});
```

It can technically work with `map` as well, but in general `map` should be used when you want to create a new array, and not to update in-place.

```
let newArray = myArray.map(item => {
    return {
        key: item.name,
        name: item.key,
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` to interchange `name` and `key`.

```js
const input = [{ name: "name1", key: "12weqw3123123"},{ name: "name2", key: "1231231rasd"}, { name: "name3", key: "sa43214dasd"}],
      result = input.map(({name, key}) => ({name: key, key: name}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Q: What does CSS class `as-console-wrapper` do?

Comment: It moves the console output to the top of the div.